# Duplicate upstream error when hosting more than 1 simple wordpress site with Nginx

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I’ve managed to host a basic wordpress site on my raspberry pi (just a test site with barely anything on it) which is working correctly, but when trying to host a second wordpress site the exact same way as the first causes a duplicate upstream error:

```
rpi nginx[3001]: nginx: [emerg] duplicate upstream "wp-php-handler" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/test.wpsite.co.uk.conf:1
```

Maybe the `wp-php-handler` can only be used once. Does anyone know how to fix this so I can host multiple wordpress sites rather than just one? I’m also hosting other non-wordpress test sites on different domains that literally just have one page (I’m learning Nginx to host my own sites), although the conf files are configured differently to the wordpress sites and do not use `wp-php-handler`. From the tutorial I followed, I assume `wp-php-handler` may be required to run wordpress sites.

Here is the test.wpsite.co.uk.conf file in /etc/nginx/sites-available (also symlinked to sites-enabled):

```
upstream wp-php-handler {
        server unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
}
server {
        listen 1234;
        server_name _;
        root /var/www/test.wpsite.co.uk;
        index index.php;
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass wp-php-handler;
        }
}
```

Note: it’s the same as the first (working) wordpress site but just with different port and root values. Whenever I remove the second wordpress site, the nginx server is able to restart and run successfully again, so I'm sure the second wordpress site is causing a problem.

Here’s what’s returned when running `journalctl -xe`:

```
lines 4736-4758/4758 (END)
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A reload job for unit nginx.service has begun execution.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 1463.
Sep 04 07:52:42 rpi nginx[3001]: nginx: [emerg] duplicate upstream "wp-php-handler" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/test.wpsite.co.uk.conf:1
Sep 04 07:52:42 rpi systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
-- Subject: Unit process exited
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- An ExecReload= process belonging to unit nginx.service has exited.
-- 
-- The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
Sep 04 07:52:42 rpi systemd[1]: Reload failed for A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
-- Subject: A reload job for unit nginx.service has finished
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A reload job for unit nginx.service has finished.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 1463 and the job result is failed.
Sep 04 07:52:42 rpi sudo[2998]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

And here’s what’s returned when running `systemctl status nginx.service`:

```
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2021-09-03 17:39:57 UTC; 14h ago
       Docs: man:nginx(8)
    Process: 1673 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 1782 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 3009 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; -s reload (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 1783 (nginx)
      Tasks: 5 (limit: 973)
     CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
             ├─1783 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
             ├─1784 nginx: worker process
             ├─1785 nginx: worker process
             ├─1786 nginx: worker process
             └─1787 nginx: worker process

Sep 03 17:39:54 rpi systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Sep 03 17:39:57 rpi systemd[1]: Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Sep 04 07:52:42 rpi systemd[1]: Reloading A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Sep 04 07:52:42 rpi nginx[3001]: nginx: [emerg] duplicate upstream "wp-php-handler" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/test.wpsite.co.uk.conf:1
Sep 04 07:52:42 rpi systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 04 07:52:42 rpi systemd[1]: Reload failed for A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Sep 04 07:54:57 rpi systemd[1]: Reloading A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Sep 04 07:54:57 rpi nginx[3009]: nginx: [emerg] duplicate upstream "wp-php-handler" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/test.wpsite.co.uk.conf:1
Sep 04 07:54:57 rpi systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 04 07:54:57 rpi systemd[1]: Reload failed for A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

Thanks for any help here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that changing `wp-php-handler` to `wp-php-handler-two` for the new wordpress site's conf file made it work